# CustomEvent bubbling from ReactJS ref

Tags: reactjs, event-bubbling

We built a framework that uses `bubbling` `CustomEvent`s to communicate from DOM nodes to the `document`.

The system dispatches the bubbling event on a DOM node by grabbing from `this.refs` in a `React.Component`.

This has been working fantastic for 99% of the scenarios. However, sometimes the component unmounts and remounts out of our control and when this happens, the handler that dispatches the bubbling CustomEvent is now dispatching on what appears to be a detached DOM node.

What is the best way to dispatch `bubbling` events from a React component to ensure this does not happen?